# MacOS python pyusb/libusb access denied to ev3 mindstroms

Tags: python, macos, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I know there are a lot of anwsers to this question, but so far nothing has worked for me.

On MacOS Big Sur (m1 mac), when running my script (with or without sudo) it says: Access denied (insufficient permissions)

I am using the ev3-dc library. Any help would be amazing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @PedroBeirão! Please tell us, how exactly you are running your script as well as what your scirpt contains so we can see where the problem comes from. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that pyusb was unable to access the ev3 mindstorms. So I made a pull request to change it to to hidapi and it works great.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For the above, specifically could you provide a link to the pull request / source code. Or include a source code snippet to show what you did to fix the issue?